# Persisting python objects using peewee

Tags: python-3.x, peewee, falconframework

This is my user object

```
class User(BaseModel):

    _email = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    _first_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    _last_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    _profile_image = CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    _gender = CharField(max_length=255, default=None)

    def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name):
        self._email = email
        self._first_name = first_name
        self._last_name = last_name
        self._profile_image = None
        self._gender = None
    def serialize(self):
       user_map = {}
       for attr, value in self.__dict__.items():
          user_map[attr[1:]] = value
       return user_map
```

This is the BaseModel object

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    _create_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    _modified_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

This is how the database is defined,

```
db = SqliteDatabase('cmp_v0.db')


def before_request_handler():
    db.connect()


def after_request_handler():
    db.close()
```

This is the User resource,

```
class UserResource:
    def on_get(self, req, res):
        user = User('someone@email.com', 'Firstname', 'Lastname')
        res.body = json.dumps(user.serialize())
```

This is the code that creates a REST endpoint

```
api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/user', UserResource())
```

When I go to the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/user
I get the following error,

```
instance._data[self.att_name] = value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is coming from your `User` constructor that assigns values to `_email`, `_first_name`, etc. Those are your field definitions, don't assign data to those names - you should use the same name but *without* the underscore in front.

When you set things like `_email` you're overriding your field definition and then Peewee gets super confused because the field definition it's expecting to use has gone when you try and set a instance value.

So this constructor works:

```
class User(BaseModel):

    _email = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    _first_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    _last_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    _profile_image = CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    _gender = CharField(max_length=255, default=None)

    def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name):
        self.email = email # note the lack of underscores
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.profile_image = None
        self.gender = None
```

As a side note, your `serialize` method has an issue too as it's outputting JSON like this:

```
{"mail": "someone@email.com", "irst_name": "Firstname",
 "rofile_image": null, "ast_name": "Lastname", "ender": null}
```

Whereas I think you wanted this:

```
{"gender": null, "first_name": "Firstname", 
 "last_name": "Lastname", "profile_image": null, "email": "someone@email.com"}
```

The code for that is this:

```
     def serialize(self):
       user_map = {}
       for attr, value in self.__dict__.items():
          user_map[attr] = value # note the change here
       return user_map
```

Annnd finally: by overriding `__init__` and not calling the super class (your `BaseModel`) you're not getting the field definitions of `_create_at` and `_modified_at` on your `UserModel`.

For that to work you'll need to do something like this:

```
        def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name):
            super(User,self).__init__()
            self.email = email
```

but then I find your `serialize` function stops working - however, initial question solved!

#### Update

I went back over Peewee's documentation, including it's [Quickstart](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#model-definition), and decided that there's an entirely better way of doing this: not to use custom constructors at all.

The code below is fully functional and avoids custom constructors. It doesn't wrap anything in Falcon because it's not relevant to the problem and keeps it simpler.

```
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('cmp_v0.db')
db.connect()


class BaseModel(Model):
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    modified_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        database = db


class User(BaseModel):

    # These are
    email = CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_image = CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
    gender = CharField(max_length=255, default=None)

    def serialize(self):
        user_map = {}
        for attr, value in self.__dict__.items():
            user_map[attr] = value
        return user_map

db.create_tables([User], safe=True)

user_row_count = len(User.select())
user = User(email='someone{}@example.com'.format(user_row_count+1),
            first_name='Firstname',
            last_name='Lastname',
            profile_image='',
            gender='')

print 'User {} {} {}'.format(user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name)
print 'Timestamps {} {}'.format(user.created_at,
                                user.modified_at)
user.save()
```

It all works, well, through the magic of Python and Peewee.

I've not read Peewee's source code, but it'll follow a familiar pattern:

The field declarations i.e. `CharField` are class-level; if you inspect the `User` class using something like ipython you'll see that `User.first_name` is present.

When a new `User` is created, Peewee will handle the construction in the background and produces a `User` instance that intercepts all read/writes of the attribute values via Python's `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`.

When a `User` instance has it's `save()` called, it'll probably use the class-level field declarations to validate & construct the SQL queries to save.

Comment: That's super helpful, though I've a question. _email and email are two different variables right, don't I now end up with two different variables?

Comment: I guess my question is, how  does a user constructed using `email` translate to `_email` in the database.

Comment: I've put a better way (through just reading the docs more closely) - which removes the `_` prefixes because that's not the Peewee way (and might even break things).  I hope that helps clear things up a bit.